# How do I enable multi-row layout for the workspace switcher applet in Metacity?

Tags: gnome-panel, workspaces, metacity

I'm looking for a way to increase number of rows in workspaces layout, using Metacity with no Compiz installed.

i.e. 3 cols and 2 rows. Using `gconf-editor` I can only change number of workspaces horizontally, but not vertically, even if it seems to be possible.

I'm working on a Ubuntu 11.04 machine with classic Gnome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key you are looking for is

```
/apps/panel/applets/workspace_switcher_screen0/prefs/num_rows
```

Comment: @jst: If my post answered your question, please click the checkmark next to my answer to mark it as accepted. :)